# Sharepoint repository migration

Tags: 2007

I just recently joined a company where someone else has developed a sharepoint 2007 portal which contains documents on every portal sites and and it uses sqlserver 2005 database and it has some annonymous database access rejection problems and the site is terribly slow due to machine and other installation factors.

Now they gave me this task to buid another server, install fresh copy of MOSS 2007 and copy the repository of already installed moss 2007 on new server so we won't loose the contents.

Can anyone guide me how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google around for reattaching the content database onto a MOSS environment.

You'll basically need to build your installation, scale it out as you need for performance, then recreate the managed paths, web applications & site collections, then use STSADM to attach the content database from your old environment.

Comment: hummm...cant i have some kinda step by step instruction thing?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep everything structured as-is, then that's relatively easy.

Take a look here:
[Is it possible to migrate a SharePoint implementation from an older to newer machine?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/is-it-possible-to-migrate-a-sharepoint-implementation-from-an-older-to-newer-mach/6399#6399)